# print the elements of an array added to a number awk

Tags: awk

if I have the following bash variable:

```
$ echo "${pos}"

201
719
744
205
354
```

The following produces...

```
!#bin/bash
(
    IFS=: 
    awk -v str2="$pos" -v sep="[$IFS]" '
        BEGIN {
            m = split(str2, b, sep)
            for (i=1; i<=m; ++i) {print b[i]}
        }
    '
)

-----------------
$ ./myscript.sh

201
719
744
205
354
```

but then doing

```
(
    IFS=: 
    awk -v str2="$pos" -v sep="[$IFS]" '
        BEGIN {
            m = split(str2, b, sep)
            for (i=1; i<=m; ++i) {print b[i]+10}
        }
    '
)

------
./myscript.sh

211
```

so the addition is working, but not printing results for all elements. why not?

Comment: sorry - have added a minimum working example. I still get the same result however

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a variable `pos` that contains:

```
201
719
744
205
354
```

Presumably your intent is that each line should become a value in an array, i.e. the values are separated by newlines. You then have code that says:

```
IFS=: 
awk -v str2="$pos" -v sep="[$IFS]" '
    BEGIN {
        m = split(str2, b, sep)
```

so by `IFS=: ... sep="[$IFS]" ... split(...,sep)` you are telling awk to split `pos` at every occurrence of `:` instead of at every newline. The result is that the array `b` only contains 1 entry and that is the entire contents of the variable `pos`. So in the above, `m` is `1` and your loop:

```
for (i=1; i<=m; ++i) {print b[i]}
```

only loops once and just prints `b[1]` which is the whole string:

```
201
719
744
205
354
```

and when you do arithmetic on that to add `1`, awk strips everything from the first non-digit to the end of the string (as it does every time you do a numeric operation on a string that contains non-digits after leading digits) and adds 1 to what is left so you get `201 + 1 = 202`.

You would need to set `IFS=$'\n'` instead of `IFS=':'` in your script but it's not clear why your script is written that way. I think you may be mixing up how to pass the contents of a shell array to awk vs how to pass the value of a shell variable to awk. Also, as an aside, shebangs are written `#!`, not `!#`.

Here is how to init and print the contents of an array in awk:

```
$ pos="201
719
744
205
354"

$ awk -v str2="$pos" '
BEGIN {
    m = split(str2, b)
    for (i=1; i<=m; ++i) {
        print b[i], "+ 1 =", b[i]+1
    }
}'
201 + 1 = 202
719 + 1 = 720
744 + 1 = 745
205 + 1 = 206
354 + 1 = 355
```

or if you really want to split on just newlines:

```
$ IFS=$'\n'
$ awk -v str2="$pos" -v sep="$IFS" '
BEGIN {
    m = split(str2, b, sep)
    for (i=1; i<=m; ++i) {
        print b[i], "+ 1 =", b[i]+1
    }
}'
201 + 1 = 202
719 + 1 = 720
744 + 1 = 745
205 + 1 = 206
354 + 1 = 355
```

Compared to what you had:

```
$ IFS=':'
$ awk -v str2="$pos" -v sep="$IFS" '
BEGIN {
    m = split(str2, b, sep)
    for (i=1; i<=m; ++i) {
        print "<" b[i] "> + 1 =", b[i]+1
    }
}'
<201
719
744
205
354> + 1 = 202
```

Answer (score 2):

It sounds weird. I tried to reproduce your problem, but I didn't succeed.
Are you sure about the content of your array ?
You can also iterate in your array in another way :

```
for i in {1..5}; do echo $i; done | awk '{a[$0]=$0}END{for(i in a) print a[i]+10 }'
```

It works for me and I hope it solves your problem.

Comment: I must be reading in the variable incorrectly into awk... I'll keep trying an update if I find the answer